# Trouble to solve that $\mathbb C^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^+ \times {\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

How can I show that $\mathbb C^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^+  \times {\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$?

I am unable to get the required isomorphism.Please help me.

Comment: Hint: any non-zero complex number can be written as $re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$…

Comment: Consider the map $\Bbb R^+\times \Bbb R$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x\cos(2\pi y)+xi\sin(2\pi y)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming our groups are $(\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$, $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}, +)$ (the group operations must be clear), we can have $\phi: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $ be such that:
$$\phi(z) = (|z|, \frac{arg(z)}{2\pi})$$
We have
$$\phi(zw) = (|zw|, \frac{arg(z) + arg(w)}{2\pi}) = \phi(z)\phi(w)$$
And 
$$\phi^{-1}(r, \alpha) = re^{2\pi\alpha i}$$ 
From which follows $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: How can $\frac {arg z} {2\pi} \in  {\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$?Is it a left coset of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb R$ or is it a real number?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear.
$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ means the elements of the form $a + \mathbb{Z}$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$, right?
And $a + \mathbb{Z} = b + \mathbb{Z}$ iff $a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$, that is, iff the fractional part of a and b are equal. So the distinct elements in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are the elements with distinct fractional part.
So $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is, informally, the set $[0, 1)$, with addition being the fractional part of the sum.